# Fractional Laplacian on the torus

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Consider the Laplacian on the $n$ dimensional torus $T$, given by $-\Delta : L^2 \rightarrow L^2$. Let the domain of $-\Delta$ be all $C^\infty$ functions initially. Now consider the Friedrichs extension of $-\Delta$, still called $-\Delta$. I want to find explicitly what the domain of $(-\Delta)^{1/2}$ is. Intuitively it seems to me that it should be all $L^2$ functions $u$ such that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} u \in L^2, k = 1, 2,...,n$, but cannot prove it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit after Neal's comment: Instead of $-\Delta$, let's say, we consider the following operator $-A = \sum^n_{i = 1} X_i^2$, where $X_i$ are vector fields generating the tangent space at each point, and $A \geq 0$, symmetric and densely defined on $L^2$, so that we can use the Friedrich's extension on $A$. Can we still say that the domain of $A^{1/2}$ consists exactly of all $L^2$ functions $u$ such that $X_i u \in L^2$ for all $i$? Thanks for your time.

Comment: In general, the natural domain of $(-\Delta)^s$ is the Sobolev space $H^s$. You might find this helpful: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.4345.pdf

Comment: @Neal I edited the question a bit for a little additional clarification. Thanks!

Comment: Be careful, there are several definitions of the fractional laplacian on bounded domains, see http://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.6195v3.pdf